# Any constant function is a Fourier Multiplier in $L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)$?

Tags: fourier-analysis, lp-spaces, fourier-transform

The function identically 1, is a Fourier Multiplier in $L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)$ ($1<p<\infty$)?
As I see it, by means of Mikhlin's theorem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplier_(Fourier_analysis)#Mikhlin_multiplier_theorem), it is verified that the function 1 satisfies said estimate, therefore, it is a multiplier, but it continues to surprise me that every constant function is a multiplier.

Comment: Multiplying by $1$ just means doing nothing! This is the identity. Of course it preserves $L^p$ integrability.